# Iframe tag in Inner HTML not rendering - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using the Angular 7 project and I want to show content that stores string data with some HTML tags. So I am binding it with a **p** tags like

```
<p [innerHTML]="article.contents"></p>
```

So the result is showing only text in tag **p, br, li** and more. But it's didn't rendered the **iframe** tags. I'm not sure what I am missing. Thanks.

See my work below: (Article is in **JSON** format)

```
article: {
    id: ""
    contents:"<p>Construction Updates of The Seagate Suite on 3rd January 2020. Our construction team 
              completed 43 Floor and continues to build the perfect condo for you.</p><iframe 
              class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" 
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aGREN6-MRfA? showinfo=0"></iframe><p><br></p>"
    }
```

This is what it's rendered

[image]

This is what it shows when I tried to inspect the element

[image]

Comment: Your iframe code is not correct and missing a closing quote `"` in `src`.

Comment: @Roy Oh that's working.